# Extract javascript variable using regex and beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

Relevant Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
         var dataJson = "";
         var grid = $("#projectTable");
         var pagerDiv = $("#pagingDiv").attr('id');
         var gridId = $("#projectTable").attr('id');
         var fileType = '1';
         var quarterId = '78';
         var totalPages = 0;
         var json = '{"total":3,"records":44,"page":1}'
</script>
```

Using BeautifulSoup and re, how do I extract the value of json variable of javascript?

Comment: What did you already try? What concrete issues are you facing? Thanks for considering [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @sudmat Check whether my answer does what u need.

Answer (score 0):

This should help u:

```
script = """
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
         var dataJson = "";
         var grid = $("#projectTable");
         var pagerDiv = $("#pagingDiv").attr('id');
         var gridId = $("#projectTable").attr('id');
         var fileType = '1';
         var quarterId = '78';
         var totalPages = 0;
         var json = '{"total":3,"records":44,"page":1}'
</script>
"""

txt = script.split(';')[-1]

txt = txt.split("'")

txt = ''.join(txt[1])

print(txt)
```

Output:

```
{"total":3,"records":44,"page":1}
```

Or u can also do it like this:

```
txt = script.split('var json = ')[-1].split("'")[1]

print(txt)
```

Output:

```
{"total":3,"records":44,"page":1}
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex might be more than you need but necessary if you cannot be sure of the spacing between `var`, `json`, `=`, etc. or the context in which the statement is in (if it might be on the same line as another JavaScript statement). If the JavaScript is always the standard form presented, then there are better ways (see methods 2 and 3)

```
(?:^|\s|;)var\s+json\s*=\s*'([^']+)
```

[See regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RyjOZh/4/)

```
import re

text = """<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
         var dataJson = "";
         var grid = $("#projectTable");
         var pagerDiv = $("#pagingDiv").attr('id');
         var gridId = $("#projectTable").attr('id');
         var fileType = '1';
         var quarterId = '78';
         var totalPages = 0;
         var json = '{"total":3,"records":44,"page":1}'
</script>"""

m = re.search(r"""(?:^|\s|;)var\s+json\s*=\s*'([^']+)'""", text, re.M)
if m:
    print(m.group(1))
```

Prints:

```
{"total":3,"records":44,"page":1}
```

**Method 2: Without Regex**

```
text = """<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
         var dataJson = "";
         var grid = $("#projectTable");
         var pagerDiv = $("#pagingDiv").attr('id');
         var gridId = $("#projectTable").attr('id');
         var fileType = '1';
         var quarterId = '78';
         var totalPages = 0;
         var json = '{"total":3,"records":44,"page":1}'
</script>"""

lines = text.split('\n')
for line in lines:
    if 'var json =' in line:
        arr = line.split("'")
        json = arr[1]
        break
print(json)
```

Prints:

```
{"total":3,"records":44,"page":1}
```

**Method 3: With Regex**

If you can be sure of the input being standard, then a simpler, more efficient regex can be used.

```
var json = '([^']+)'
```

[See regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RyjOZh/3/)

```
import re

text = """<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
         var dataJson = "";
         var grid = $("#projectTable");
         var pagerDiv = $("#pagingDiv").attr('id');
         var gridId = $("#projectTable").attr('id');
         var fileType = '1';
         var quarterId = '78';
         var totalPages = 0;
         var json = '{"total":3,"records":44,"page":1}'
</script>"""

m = re.search(r"""var json = '([^']+)'""", text)
if m:
    print(m.group(1))
```

Prints:

```
{"total":3,"records":44,"page":1}
```